# changing drop down menu to avoid long anchors

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I made a drop down menu and while it works fine and acts exactly like I want it to there is one issue which I can't seem to correct.

For some of the drop downs I am putting a little comment underneath to assist the user.  For instance :

```
<a href="/#"><b>test</b> <br/><span>testing comment</span></a>
```

Rather than having the comment inside the anchor I would like to have it outside of it and look/act in the same fashion.  Reasoning... Google scares me and I don't want them to think I am keyword stuffing... especially since the drop downs are initially display:hidden.  I am thinking something like :

```
<a href="/#"><b>test</b></a> <br /><span>testing comment</span></
```

Must be possible some way, but I cannot seem to get it.  Full code and css at this fiddle - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn7qr/)

```
<div class="drop-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="full" href="/#">number 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/#"><b>test</b> <br/><span>testing comment</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#"><b>test</b> <br/><span>testing comment</span></a></li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li><a href="/#"><b>testing</b> <br/><span>testing comment</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/#">number 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="purchase" href="/#"><img alt="cart" height="16" src="/images/trans.gif" width="16"> number 3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="full" href="/#">number 4</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/#">testing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#">testing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/#">testing</a></li>
                        </ul>                   
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/#">number 5</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I still don't understand your problem?

Comment: So just to clarify if you want that under-comment look why can't you use <a href="/#"><b>test</b></a> <br /><span>testing comment</span>... Please explain what you want more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<li><a href="/#"><b>test</b></a><span>testing comment</span></li>
```

and when you hover over `li` the background will have the same effect.

```
.drop-menu li ul li:hover {
  background:#c4dcec;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: With a few style changes that will do it! Now, is it possible to have that entire <li> clickable based on its anochor?  I think I remember doing something like this were the a was absolute positioned and 100% or something like that.

Comment: Can't seem to get the padding correct either for the span portion - its positioned lower than I want below its anchor text.

Comment: spanning fixed - would still like to know if I can make the entire <li>'s clickable though - even with the above changes.

Comment: ...and I also found out this does not work in ie7 whereas it did previously.